# How to align only the title in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I would like to align center only the title in UIAlertView, while the message should be align left.

Currently I am doing

```
((UILabel*)[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

But it aligns center also the message.

Comment: Thats a really dangerous way of accessing subviews.  If you really want to customize the way an alertview looks, you probably want to make your own custom alertview.  Try [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to modify the default labels of the UIAlertView, instead you should create a new UILabel and add it as a subview.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Centered Title" message:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 24.0, 250.0, 80.0)];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = @"Here is an example of a left aligned label in a UIAlertView!";
[alert addSubview:label];
[alert show];
```

[image]