# How to change message's aligment in UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, css, uialertview

When I use UIAlertView,I find the message's textAligment is Center. e.g.,When I write this code:

```
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil
                                                   message:@"this is first line     \nsecondLine should be center"
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertView show];
```

the effect is follow:[image]
　　As we see, the text"this is first line" is in the center,but I want to change it to left.I know UILabel can change text's alignment,but I don't know whether can I change it in UIAlertView.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code like this.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil
                                               message:nil
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


UILabel *v = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
v.text = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
v.numberOfLines = 0;
v.text = @"this is first line\nsecondLine should be center";
[alert setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Yes,it works.But I want to know the key "accessoryView".  does any document refer to it?  In addition, set the frame of the label"v" does not work.

Comment: But it works in NSAlert,which is useful in mac development. does UIAlertView the same?

Comment: "accessoryView" is private. So, this may your app rejected. So, i recommend you to UIAlertViewController / customise your alert.

Comment: oh,do you mean "accessory View" is not declared in the .h file? so it is private.    But if it is declared in the .h file but not declared as a property, is it private either?

Comment: In addition, how to find the private variable or private method in a class.I'm very interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

iOS7: For left alignment, you can do this:

```
NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subviews;
for(int x = 0; x < [subViewArray count]; x++){

    //If the current subview is a UILabel...
    if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

Ref: [How to make a multiple line, left-aligned UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571315/how-to-make-a-multiple-line-left-aligned-uialertview)

Or you can add an UILabel to alertView:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Centered Title" message:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 24.0, 250.0, 80.0)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"Here is an example of a left aligned label in a UIAlertView!";
    [alert addSubview:label];
    [alert show];
```

Ref: [How to align only the title in UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789098/how-to-align-only-the-title-in-uialertview)

Comment: I try to use this solution.But I find the subViewArray has no object in it.

Comment: @huixing Yes, it just works for iOS <= 7. I edited my answer.